# How to open document file in microsoft word. Coding in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I'm trying to open my document file in Microsoft Word. Currently, I can open the app but I can't view or edit my file. Any help please?

Here is my code :

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final file = await _downloadFile(url, filename);
      try {
        AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
          action: 'action_view',
          data: file.path,
          type: "application/msword",
          flags: [Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, Flag.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION],
        );
        await intent.launch();
      } on PlatformException catch(e){
        // Microsoft word has not been installed
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) package.

Comment: Can I choose the destination app with Openfilex?